# String replace in Android

Tags: android

To try string replace in Android, I wrote a small snippet:

```
public class cs{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   String a,c;
   int b;
   b=1;
   c="12345";
   a="12345,54321";
   a.replace(c，String.valueOf(b));
   System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

**Expected Output:** 12345,54321 changes to 1,54321

**Actual Output:** 12345，54321
。Please help。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `.` in `c.String.valueOf(b)` a typo for a comma, separating two parameters? Because it doesn't make much sense as stated. `replace` accepts two parameters, and furthermore, it doesn't change the string it's executed on, it merely returns a new one, so you need to pick up that return value and reassign it to the variable:

```
a = a.replace(c, String.valueOf(b));
```

Answer (score -2):

If you expect output 1,54321 you need to write

a.replace("12345", c.String.valueOf(b));